# CSS select by class which is children of id

Tags: css

It seems that I can't select an element by it's class when I already selected it's parent by it's id in CSS. What could be the problem here?

```
<div id="desktopCloseIconQuickAction" class='shown'>
  <span class="icon-label">Close</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#desktopCloseIconQuickAction {
 font-size: 13px; 
 position: absolute; 
 overflow: hidden; 
 right: -115px; 
 top: 15px; 
 z-index: 9; 
 width: 70px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: all 0.6s;
}

#desktopCloseIconQuickAction.shown {
 right: 15px;
 opacity: 1;
}

#desktopCloseIconQuickAction .icon_label {
 display: inline;
 opacity: 0;
 padding-right: 5px;
 transition: all 0.6s;
 color: green;
}
```

Why isn't the text "CLOSE" in the span turning green, or disappearing?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1t8rumc5/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a typo, in the HTML the span class is defined as

```
.icon-label
```

but in the CSS it is

```
.icon_label
```

Comment: ... Thanks for pointing that out... I was looking at this code for like 35 minutes now, and didn't notice:|

Comment: Happens to all of us. It often helps if a fresh pair of eyes is looking at it.

Answer (score 0):

you have an error writing your class name as you have given **class="icon-label"** to span and wrote css for class **icon_label** just replace the underscore (_) with hyphen(-) then all correct.